# Is it possible to create views dynamically in VS Code extension development?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an extension for a special purpose. I got a statically generated views in package.json as below.

```
"views": {
      "display-tree": [
        {
          "id": "displaytree",
          "name": "MyTree",
          "icon": "media/logo.svg",
          "contextualTitle": "Tree"
        }
      ]
    }
```

While the extension is running I want to dynamically generate it based on requirements. Is it possible to do this?

I am creating static treeview as follows inside the code.

```
export class TreeView {
    constructor(context: vscode.ExtensionContext){
        const view = vscode.window.createTreeView('displaytree', { treeDataProvider: aNodeWithIdTreeDataProvider(), showCollapseAll: true });
        context.subscriptions.push(view);
    }
}
```